# How to clear comments

Tags: support, feature-request

### The Problem

Some questions start out flawed, this summons a wave of either

1. Support and suggestions on how to improve
2. Tonnes of whining about how it is a crap question

Both of these really distract from the question being answered once it is improved.

### The question

How can someone have their comments section cleared?

E.g. my question has 13 comments, I do not wish to flag each and every one as "no longer relevant".

### My solution

I believe there should be a button in the "On hold..." popup where you can click for a moderator to swing by and check out if it is fixed yet. Then if they deem it a good enough question they can "restart" the question with 0 comments.

Almost like a "summon a moderator for an MOT" option.

Comment: Check if the question is fixed? Any edits to an on-hold or closed question _immediately_ put it in the "reopen queue" where users vote whether to leave it or to reopen it. So if you "fixed" an on-hold question, it should go in the queue. It's up to the reviewers to decide whether it should be reopened or not. Some people may vote to reopen, but it can take time before it is reopened as it takes 5 votes to do so.

Comment: @FoxElemental No; the automatic entry into the reopen review queue is only for questions in the "on hold" state. Questions that have transitioned to "closed" needs one reopen vote to be pushed into the queue, as I recall. (This should be easy to get if the edit actually fixes the issues and someone who sees it has at least the reputation necessary to talk in [chat].)

Answer (score 5):

You can use flags to draw moderators' attention to things.

But help us out!  You asked "for a moderator to swing by and check out if it is fixed yet", but unless it's obvious (arguments, "whining", etc), we can only tell by digging through the edit history and all the comments, comparing timestamps.  That's a lot of work, so what we're more likely to do is skim the comments looking for anything that still seems to be outstanding and either purge or migrate the rest.  Or decline your flag if we can't understand, so be sure to check your flag responses (link on your profile page) for messages.  If you can instead tell us the comments were addressed in an edit, that's a big help.

On flag responses, I mean this link on your "activity" profile tab:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can delete your own comments.

In order to "delete" comments from others, you need to flag these (just on will do). If you think this is justified, choose "in need of moderator intervention " and explain why. Comments will likely end up dumped in a chat room nobody will use but at least they will remain in case somebody wants to read them.